# Cordova plugin phonenumbers crashes on iOS latest versions

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-phonenumbers to access the contacts.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts-phonenumbers

It works fine on older versions. It crashes on newer iOS versions as soon as when i am trying to access the contacts. This is how i am includng the plugin in config.xml.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts-phonenumbers">
    <param name="CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app wants to access your Contacts"/>
</plugin>
```

Is there anything else needs to be added? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin doesn't have a variable for setting the usage description, so what you are trying to do won't work.

Try setting the usage description using the `edit-config` tag in the config.xml instead

```
<edit-config target="NSContactsUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need contacts access to search friends</string>
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on the config.xml

```
 <platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSContactsUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>Accessing contacts allows you to...</string>
    </config-file>
```